# Does the operating system assumes anything about callee-saved registers when control returns to it?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, operating-system

> Does the operating system assumes anything about callee-saved registers when control returns to it?

I've wondered whether the OS, say Windows, assumes anything about the callee-saved registers like `ebp, esi, edi`?

In other words, does the OS require the value in any of these registers preserved, when control transfers back to it (`ret` in `main`)?

I cannot find anything specified, but I guess the answer is no (having looked at compiler generated code). Is there any documentation on the topic?

Comment: Windows, being language agnostic, always had its own ABI.  Compilers need to accommodate it, they all do.  Calling convention is stdcall (right to left, callee cleans up), eax, ecx and edx are scratch, return values in eax, the rest are preserved.  Stdcall is documented about everywhere.

Comment: @HansPassant - What I mean is the following:  When my assembly program transfer control to the OS by returning from the entry point function, does the OS assume anything about the registers? I guess this has nothing to do with Stdcall?

Comment: @HansPassant - The topmost address at the stack (when starting the program) returns to Kernel32, right? Does it assume something about preserved registers? In other words, should, e.g., `esi` be preserved?

Comment: Any language runtime support library calls ExitProcess() to terminate the process.  So they can set the process exit code.  You will not have to worry about preserving anything when you use RET instead, the kernel was written to deal with badly behaving entry points.

Comment: when returning to OS, a proper secure OS should survive any mischief done by app, otherwise it would be possible to misuse such behaviour for DoS attack, or even worse. So in this special case (returning to OS) you can hurt only yourself, but as long as you properly call exit process, everything else doesn't matter.

Comment: any functions must save *ebx*, *esi*, *edi*, *esp*, *ebp* in *x86* and *rbx*, *rsi*, *rdi*, *rbp*, *rsp*, *r12-r15* in *x64* . entry point not exception. even if current implementation (system code which call your *EP*) and not used this registers, this can changed in another version. if you write on c/c++ or another high level language compiler auto save-restore all non-volatile registers, if you write function on assembler - you must yourself save/restore non volatile registers, which you modify in function.

Comment: Are you asking about whether OPERATING SYSTEM has register expectations when you call a system service or are you asking about general function calls?

Comment: The return in main does not return to the operating system, it returns to some entry function that called main. Normally a process is terminated via a call to [ExitProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658(v=vs.85).aspx) .

Comment: @rcgldr - does this function expect registers to be preserved?

Comment: Depends, if we are talking for example about C++ application, the `clib` has some initialization code ran before calling `main`, and after return it will do de-initialization, like calling of registered `atexit(...)`, calling destructors of global/static variables, flushing stream buffers, etc... how much robust that code is depends on the particular `clib` implementation (may even change with version update), that code is part of your application, not OS. Generally you should try to follow the ABI if possible, and usually that's not hard to do. But it will not affect the OS, just the app.

Comment: @Shuzheng - For ExitProcess, the registers do not have to be preserved, but the exit code is passed as a parameter, so if in 32 bit standard call mode, the exit code will need to be pushed onto the stack, but esp doesn't have to match the original value.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294072/does-the-win32-entry-point-have-to-preserve-any-registers-values-callee-saved-r.  But note that's about the Win32 entry point in your process *not* the `main()` that's eventually called by CRT code.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 32 is designed to have process isolation.
Nothing<sup>*</sup> that a process does can cause another process (including) the operating system itself to fail.
For this reason it does not matter what you do with the registers upon exit.

The only exception is `esp`. If the stack pointer is messed up your application will terminate with a stack fault or access violation.
This will still not affect the OS however, it will merely terminate your app slightly early.

<sup>*</sup>*Obviously this does not include the effects on the system by legitimate system calls, or the exploitation of bugs.*

Note that the `ret` in `main` does **not** return control to the OS. Almost all Win32 `c` applications have a runtime library included. If so the `ret` in `main` returns to some initialization code that look like this:

```
//pseudo-init

do set up (setup command line params for main to read).
call main;
call Windows.ExitProcess();
```

Having a 'clean' exit to Windows is important to an application so it can clean up its own resources (close files etc). The OS does not really care. If an application does not clean up after itself, the OS will do the job for it.
Much worse than having a crashing up is a 'hung' one. If an application is stuck in an endless loop, or worse an endless loop that keeps claiming more and more resources then the system can be brought to its knees quite easily.

Comment: By upon exit, you mean when my application transfers control to the OS (the function calling my application entry point) by `ret` ?