# If I am using the Win32 entry point, should I increase the esp value to remove the variables from the stack?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

If I am using the Win32 entry point and I have the following code (in NASM):

```
extern _ExitProcess@4

global _start

section .text
_start:
    mov ebp, esp

    ; Reserve space onto the stack for two 4 bytes variables
    sub esp, 4
    sub esp, 4

    ; ExitProcess(0)
    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
```

Now before exiting the process, should I increase the `esp` value to remove the two variables from the stack like I do with any "normal" function?

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as your last question

Comment: @David Heffernan It is similar but not the same.

Comment: As I read it, if you understand the answer to the last question, then you can apply that knowledge here, no?

Comment: @David Heffernan This is what I thought at first, but then I read *Johan*'s answer in the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097434/does-the-operating-system-assumes-anything-about-callee-saved-registers-when-con?rq=1 which confused me.

Comment: no, you should not increase the `esp` - for what ?!

Comment: Writing `sub esp, 4` twice is always worse than `sub esp, 8`.  In assembly language, there's no compiler to optimize away redundancy for you.

Comment: You're calling a `_Noreturn` function, *not* returning.  So, like any other function call, no you don't need to do anything before making another call.

Comment: Johan's answer is in response to a question about returning from the application's main() function, or at least that's how Johan interpreted it.  Quite different to your situation, where you're using the Win32 entry point and not returning from it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExitProcess` api can be called from any place. in any function and sub-function. and stack pointer of course can be any. you not need set any registers (include stack pointer) to some (and which ?) values. so answer - you not need increase the esp

---

as noted @HarryJohnston of course stack must be valid and aligned. as and before **any** api call. `ExiProcess` is usual api. and can be call as any another api. and like any another api it require only valid stack but not concrete stack pointer value. non-volatile registers need restore only we **return to caller**. but `ExiProcess` not return to caller. it at all never return

so rule is very simply - if you return from any function (entry point or absolute any - does not matter) - we need restore non volatile registers (stack pointer *esp* or *rsp* based on calling conventions) and return. if we not return to caller - we and not need restore/preserve any registers. if we return from thread or process entry point, despite good practice also restore all registers as well - in current windows implementations - even if we not do this, any way all will be work, because kernel32 shell caller simply just call `ExitThread` after we return. it not use any non volatile registers or local variables here. so code will be worked even without restore this from entry point, but much better restore it anyway

Comment: +1.  Just to make it absolutely clear, though, when you call `ExitProcess` the stack pointer does have to be *valid*, that is, it has to be properly aligned (if applicable) and point to somewhere in the stack allocation.  If it has been set to zero, for example, the program will crash rather than exiting cleanly.  But it doesn't matter *where* in the stack you are.  It doesn't even matter which thread you call it from!

Comment: @HarryJohnston - of course stack must be valid and aligned . i simply assume it as default. what i try say to OP - the `ExiProcess` is usual api. and can be call as any another api. and like any another api it require only valid stack but not concrete value. non-volatile registers need restore only we **return** to caller. but `ExiProcess` not return to caller. it at all never return

Comment: @Harry Johnston I have two questions if you don't mind: 1) *"the stack pointer does have to be valid, that is, it has to be properly aligned"* What do you mean by *"properly aligned"*, do you mean the `esp` has to be 4 bytes aligned, and does it have to be aligned when I only call `ExitProcess()` or when I call any function? 2) *"and point to somewhere in the stack allocation"* What do you mean by *"stack allocation"*, do you mean the `esp` can have any value except `0`?

Comment: @user8426277 - 1) before any api call in *x86* `esp=4*n` must be. in *amd64* `rsp=16*n` must be. inside own function you formal can have any value of stack pointer (if this is user mode where no interrupts), but almost always we writing code when stack pointer all time valid. 2)"stack allocation" - are this not clear ? some memory block. and in windows every thread have own stack. it boundaries written in `NT_TIB`. stack must be in range [StackLimit, StackBase). if you swap stack - you must update data in `NT_TIB` too (for example look `SwitchToFiber`)

Comment: @user8426277, note that these are just the same requirements for calling *any* API function.  The fact that you're calling ExitProcess rather than, say, CreateFile, doesn't make any difference.  And, of course, if the stack pointer points at non-committed memory (including but not limited to zero) then *any* `call` will fail, because the first thing the `call` command does is to push the return address, so you would get a memory access violation.

Comment: @Harry Johnston *"note that these are just the same requirements for calling any API function"* Does the `esp` has to be 4 bytes aligned only for the WinAPI functions (`ExitProcess()`, `CreateFile()`, etc.) or for any function?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, if you are calling your own function, 4-byte stack alignment isn't actually mandatory but a failure to do so may cause the CPU to perform poorly.  If you are calling a Windows function or a C DLL, the compiler will expect the stack to be 4-byte aligned - I'm not sure whether there's actually a written rule about this or whether it's just taken for granted because that's what all the compilers do.   @RbMm might have a reference.

Comment: @user8426277 - on *x86* platform, not 4-byte stack alignment can formally worked without cpu exception, or can be and exception depen from cpu settings. with this *esp* every *push* and *pop* read/save 4 byte data not at *4x* address. even if no exception -  cause the CPU to perform poorly. and any api assume 4 byte esp align. and place local variables based on this. when kernel called - it check align of structs (if exist pointers to it in parameters) and raise exception - because you local structs will be misaligned with this stack. and main for what you need miss-align stack ?!

Comment: @user8426277 - on *x64* situation is more serious for align. so you must keep stack properly aligned before any api call (*16n*).